# How to structure imports in Golang test files

Tags: unit-testing, go, testing, import

I have functions defined in `main.go` that aren't accessible in `main_test.go`.  However, in some online tutorials, I see that functions are accessible: I would like to understand the difference, as well as how to structure these in a go-idiomatic way .

Specifically, I have an application with multiple binaries:

```
myapp/cmd/app/main.go
myapp/cmd/cli/main.go
```

I currently have a lot of simple unit test logic I run in the `func main` of the `main.go` files. I'm just testing individual functions and having them print their output, I'm not trying to invoke the whole power of the "testing" suite, if I can avoid it.

Since my tests in the top of my main.go are so long at this point, I would like to move them to specific test files, in for example:

```
myapp/cmd/app/main_test.go
myapp/cmd/cli/main_test.go
```

This works well enough with my makefile:

```
# Makefile

all: test build
build:
    go build -o cmd/app/main cmd/app/main.go
    go build -o cmd/cli/main cmd/cli/main.go
test:
    go test ./cmd/app/main_test.go
    go test ./cmd/cli/main_test.go
```

If I just want to run my testfiles, I'd like to take the item in my `app/main.go`

```
// cmd/app/main.go
package main

func definedInMain(m string) string {
  // 
}

func main() {
  m := definedInMain("1")
  fmt.Println(m)
  // all the rest of my app's logic...
}
```

And run it in my `main_test.go`

```
// cmd/app/main_test.go

package main

// no imports, I hope?

func testDefinedInMain() {
  m := definedInMain("1")
  fmt.Println(m)  
}
```

However, this fails with:

```
undefined: definedInMain
FAIL
```

I am confused that I have to import all these functions into my `main_test.go` files (and even when I try, it suggests `"can't load package: ... myapp/cmd/app/main" in any of: ..."`)

Is there a clean and go-idiomatic way for me to test my very simple unit tests in test files  and run my functions in main files without a lot of rewriting imports or other substantial re-architecting?

From some links, I had the impression if I made a `main_test.go`, the imports would follow on their own (as they seem to in these examples).

- https://medium.com/@thejasbabu/testing-in-golang-c378b351002d
  (where the Reverse function is not explicitly imported in reverse_test.go)
- https://tutorialedge.net/golang/intro-testing-in-go/
  (where the Calculate function is not explicitly imported in main_test.go)
- https://blog.alexellis.io/golang-writing-unit-tests/
  (where the Sum function is not explicitly imported in main_test.go)

So, you can see I am a bit confused tutorials get their functions imported for free, and I do not, and I just want to understand the magic better.

Is it just the case my function, definedInMain, is private because it's lowercased?  I do actually want this function to be private, but I'd expect it to be exported to the main_test.go file the same way it is usable in main.go.  Do I have to make it fully public to have tests in another file?  That doesn't seem correct, eg, "it is only possible to unit test public methods in go?"

Comment: Just try `go test ./cmd/app/`. Running `go build`, `go test` and `go run` commands with the package name, instead of the filename, means including all files in the package.

Comment: Thanks.  `go test ./cmd/app/`

`../../../go/src/myapp/cmd/app/main.go:10:2: local import "../../somelibrary" in non-local package
Makefile:19: recipe for target 'test' failed
make: *** [test] Error 1`

I do have a library at
`/myapp/somelibrary/somelibrary.go`

I am importing in:
`myapp/cmd/app/main.go`

Comment: Local imports are highly discouraged. Set up `$GOPATH` and import with the full path.

Comment: Thanks, this worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If @Mustafa Simav wants to post that answer, I'll accept, but if not, to close this out:

The solution was to use non-local imports with the full path below `$GOPATH`.  The whatever_test.go does get automagic imports correctly, even of non-exported, lowercase functions, which is exactly what I wanted to unit test.  This was just hard to see owing to the imports.

Comment: For future reference, the other reason this works just fine is both packages are declared "package main."  So long as you build them all, go won't see a difference and all the functions are treated as being in the same place, even if they are defined across files.